# AWS Codedeploy BlockTraffic/AllowTraffic durations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I've been using AWS CodeDeploy to push our applications live, but it always takes ages doing the BlockTraffic and AllowTraffic steps. Currently, I have an application load balancer(ALB) with three EC2 nodes initially(behind an autoscaling group). So, If I do a CodeDeploy OneAtATime, the whole process takes up to 25 minutes.

The load balancer I'm using it with had connection draining set to 300s. I thought it was the reason for drag out. However, I disabled Connection Draining and got the same results. I then enabled Connection Draining and set timeout to 5 seconds and still got the same results.

Further, I found out CodeDeploy depends on the ALB Health Check settings. according to the  AWS documentation

> After an instance is bound to the ALB, CodeDeploy waits for the
>   status of the instance to be healthy ("inService") behind the load
>   balancer. This health check is done by ALB and depends on the health
>   check configuration.

So I tried by setting low timeouts and thresholds for health check settings. Even those changes didn't reduce the deployment time much.

Can someone direct me to a proper solution to speed up the process?

Comment: Hi, Have you found any workaround for this? I am also facing the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is the de-registration of instances from the AWS target group. You want to change this value:

[image]

or find a way to update the `deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds` property - by default it's 300s, which is 5 minutes. The docs can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_TargetGroupAttribute.html)).

Comment: I set deregistration delay to 30 seconds, with 2 of 10 second health checks, but the BlockTraffic step is still consistently taking 1m30s, whereas it should be ~40s. AllowTraffic only takes 20 seconds. Any idea what else could cause it?

Comment: Maybe need to restart the codedeployagent again. not sure.